# How to efficiently match ids on two different javascript objects and merge them together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is somewhat similar to a join table. I have two different javascript objects. One of these objects is an array of objects, where one of the properties in that object is an array of ids. These ids map directly to another array of javascript objects.

ex.

```
users = [{
  name: 'Bob',
  birthday: '01-02-1990',
  favorite_color_ids: ['2', '4', '6']
},
{
....etc

}]

colors: [{
  id: 2,
  name: 'red',
  hex_val: '#FF0000'
},
{
  ...etc
}]
```

I want to create another property on each object in the users array, called 'favorite_color_names'. What would be the most efficient way to do this? Currently have many nested _.each operations.

Comment: Why have an array of colors only to give each color an unique ID? Seems like the ID should be a key used to store and reference the color in an object. Then it's super efficient to look them up. `colors: {2: {name:red, hex_val: '#FF0000'}, ...}` ... `user[0].favorite_color_names = user[0].favorite_color_ids.map(function(id) { colors[id].name; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, if you need to access the colors by ID frequently, but can't change the structure from an Array, I'd just go ahead and dynamically create an object structure that references each color by ID.

```
var colors_by_id = {}

colors.forEach(color) {
    colors_by_id[color.id] = color
})
```

Then you can make your arrays of names if you wish for each user *(though it would seem less important since you can now easily get it on the fly)*.

```
users.forEach(user) {
    user.favorite_color_names = user.favorite_color_ids.map(function(id) {
        return colors_by_id[id].name
    })
})
```